# Formatting dates in ggplot to highlight the start of financial years

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I've got data refering to financial years, starting from 1 April each year and ending 31 March in next solar year.

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2008-04-01"), by="month", length.out=49),
                 var  = rnorm(49))

head(df,3)
        date         var
1 2008-04-01  0.04265025
2 2008-05-01 -1.59671801
3 2008-06-01  0.4909673
```

Plotting `df` with `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(date, var))` I get:

[image]

Now, what I'm interested in is having say the "2009" label positioned at "2009-04-01", as it's that the actual start of the FY 2009. I managed to get that with the following code:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(date, var)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = df$date[months(df$date)=="April"],
                   labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

which correctly gives:

[image]

My question is (finally :-) ) does some of you have a better way for showing financial years and eventually better codes then the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `geom_rect` to highlight the financial years. Assuming you save your original plot as `p`, try:

```
bgdf <- data.frame(xmin=as.POSIXct(paste0(2008:2011,"-04-01")),
                   xmax=as.POSIXct(paste0(2009:2012,"-04-01")),
                   ymin=min(df$var),ymax=max(df$var),alpha=((2008:2011)%%2)*0.1)
p + geom_rect(aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),
              data=bgdf,alpha=bgdf$alpha,fill="blue")
```

Comment: Very nice (and handy) methods for `xmin`, `xmax` and `alpha`. I like them cause they allow to programmatically create the rectangles with any data, using `min(years())` and "04-01" being a parameter to eventually be changed if necessary. Thanks! It's a very general answer which applies perfectly in this case.